# Regex - Using short hand characters inside a character class

Tags: regex, grep

I'm required to do some operations which involve regular expressions.

String I'm operating on:

```
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,us
```

Basically, what I want to do is take the first two parameters (`/dev/fd0` and `/media/floppy0`) and I want to ignore everything after this. To achieve I've tried the regular expressions shown below. My question is, why do the following regular expressions produce different results?

Regular expression 1:

```
grep -o '/dev/f\S*\s*\S*' /etc/fstab
```

Output (the output that I'm expecting):

```
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0
```

Regular expression 2:

```
grep -o '/dev/f[\S]*\s*[\S]*' /etc/fstab
```

Output:

```
/dev/f
```

Regular expression 3:

```
grep -o '/dev/f[^\s]*\s[^\s]*' /etc/fstab
```

Output:

```
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,u
```

I don't see why 2 and 3 don't produce the same output as 1. The way I see it is that for 2, it shouldn't matter whether I put the non white space short hand character (`\S`) inside a character class. The same goes for 3. Furthermore, why is 2 different from 3? Isn't `[\S]` the same as `[^\s]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I can't speak to whether they "should" be different — there are many regex engines where your interpretations would be correct — but in POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BREs; the regex type that `grep` uses by default), `[\S]` is a character class containing `\` and `S`, and `[^\s]` is a character class containing all characters except `\` and `s`. (This is per the spec, which requires that, both in BREs and in EREs, "The special characters `'.'`, `'*'`, `'['`, and `'\'` (period, asterisk, left-bracket, and backslash, respectively) shall lose their special meaning within a bracket expression." [[link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)]) The within-character-class equivalent of `\s` is `[:space:]`:

```
grep -o '/dev/f[^[:space:]]*\s*[^[:space:]]*' /etc/fstab
```

Some versions of `grep` support a nonstandard `-P` option to use Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs) instead of POSIX regular expressions. Perl-compatible regular expressions do have the behavior you describe, so if your `grep` supports that option, then you can use it like this:

```
grep -o -P '/dev/f[\S]*\s*[\S]*' /etc/fstab
grep -o -P grep -o '/dev/f[^\s]*\s[^\s]*' /etc/fstab
```