# Regex for currency with special characters and whitespaces

Tags: regex, linux, grep

Hello i'm trying to filter the contents of multiple files with the grep command on linux using regular expressions, what i'm trying to achieve is get all the matches (currency or value by an ocr process) that

1 - That may or may not start with one blank space

```
[[:space:]]\{1\}
```

2 - Then it has to contain one character or one blank space on it

```
[Ss5$\s]\{1\}
```

3 - And finally has to have a number range between 0 to 9 and the characters ,.

```
[0-9,.]\+
```

But it looks like this expression doesn't cover a few possibilities like

```
 192,753.50
```

Regular expression used:

```
[[:space:]]\{1\}[Ss5$\s]\{1\}[0-9,.]\+
```

Thanks

Example output

```
Example: 
--------------------------------------------------------------
.D. OF c.B. socmvo 14,255.34 14,255.34 MN 031042013 0.00 Move
 $92,300.01 $35,333  0533110:  539101043401”
192,753.50 192,753.50 MN 037042013 0.00 Moves
51111703041211.1215 $09 
s9,247.16 $9,247.16 1.111
Current:266,768.54 USD
Total:S277.777.35 USD

Approval S277.777.35 USD
--------------------------------------------------------------

Result: 
 14,255.34 
 14,255.34
 $92,300.01 
 $35,333
 539101043401
 192,753.50
 $9,247.16

Desired: 
 14,255.34
 14,255.34
 $92,300.01 
 $35,333
 539101043401 
 192,753.50 
 192,753.50
 s9,247.16 
 $9,247.16
 266,768.54
 S277.777.35
```

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/snLvL7md/)

Comment: @RodrigoMontano not a link, post it in your question ;)

Comment: Try `[[:space:]]?([Ss5$]|\s)[0-9,.]+` (The leading space is optional, character classes mustn't contain shorthand characters unless you run grep with `-P` flag ([more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952541/regex-using-short-hand-characters-inside-a-character-class))).

Comment: not a single match @collapsar

Comment: @collapsar ok im gonna try it

Comment: Thank you @collapsar it works for most of my cases I might need to do a few corrections but its really close :)

Comment: @RodrigoMontano: what about `[[:blank:]]?(?:[Ss5$[:blank:]])[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]+)*`? Use with `-P` flag.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on your example because your regex is incorrect also it doesn't contains a character.
If you want your string contains one character or one blank space first you need to specify the type of your character if it's a word character you can use `\w` and ... for other cases, then you can use a character class like `[\w ]`.

And finally you can use following regex :

```
[[:space:]]\{1\}[\w ][0-9,.]\+[\w+ ]
```